# Word for compound event: "At least one of these events will happen"

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, nouns, phrasing, abstract-nouns

Over on [Math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3842780/intuitive-name-for-union-of-events-in-probability) I was discussing probability jargon. Typically the events considered in probability theory are constructed from other, simpler events by a series of unions, intersections, and complements, which have the following meanings:

- Complement of event *A*: "Event *A* does not happen"
- Intersection of events *A* and *B*: "Events *A* and *B* both happen"
- Union of events *A* and *B*: "At least one of the events *A*, *B* happens"

The existing jargon to describe these is imperfect for events. Although *opposite* for complement and *coincidence* for intersection work well, I had trouble finding a good event-based name for union:

> The union of two events, though, is harder to come up with a good informal name for. Terms like *umbrella*, *compass*, *ambit*, *scope*, *range*, *orbit*, *menu* which describe a list of possible selections sound weird when phrased as events that happen: "the umbrella of *A* or *B* happens if..." I thought of terms like *participation*, *intervention*, *intrusion*, *inclusion*, but these all have (literally) unwanted overtones and/or make the events sound personified in a weird way. *Occurrence* and *instance* sound better to describe "at least one of these events happens" but have the drawback that they apply to single events; there's no necessary reason for them to apply to a union of multiple events. *Concurrence* sounds like another description for intersection, as does *conjunction*, which is too jargony. *Disjunction* is also too jargony and sounds like "*A* or *B* but not both". *Option* and *choice* imply that someone in particular is picking which event happens.

> The least-bad idea that I came up with for union is **alternative**: the *alternative* of *A* or *B* happens iff at least one of *A, B* happens. Could not be used as a verb ("*A* or *B* alternate"??) but implies two or more possibilities without also implying that someone is picking which event happens, or that the events are like people "participating" or "intruding". ***Does anyone have a better one?***

So I put it to you: what's a relatively informal, single-word English expression for "the event where at least one of this group of events takes place?"

Comment: So far as its dictionary definition is concerned, *alternative* could be used for this purpose, but quite a few people will interpret that word to rule out the possibility of both events happening; to avoid that interpretation, it may be necessary to make it explicit that you are using it in the way that allows it.

Comment: Maybe you have an ***actualization*** when one or more of a set of possibilities actually occurs.

Comment: @Jim To me "actualization" has the same issue as "occurrence" and "instance". We could have an "actualization" of a single event--or even an intersection of multiple events--just as well as an "actualization" of a union of multiple events. So "actualization" isn't narrowly tailored enough to serve as an informal term for a union of multiple events, specifically.

Comment: I believe "disjunction" is often used for this.   See  https://academic.csuohio.edu/polen/LC9_Help/9/93gdr.htm

Answer (score 0):

A union really is the closest term for this, or a more extended "either one or both"; informal conversation is not as precise as a logician in its terms for abstract causes or events.

That said, if you wanted to coin another term, **inclusive** (adj., historically also n.) describes this function. Oxford English Dictionary, "[inclusive, n. and adj.](https://oed.com/view/Entry/93581)":

> [adj.] 8. Chiefly Logic and Linguistics. Designating or relating to (the use of) a disjunction (esp. ‘or’) forming compound statements which are true if and only if at least one of the component statements is true (with the possibility that both are true). Cf. earlier sense A.

The adjective form is the one commonly included in logic and mathematics under the term **inclusive or**, describing an *or* statement that should include one, the other, or both events. (In common usage, *or* is often exclusive, indicating one or the other but not both.)

That said, its use as a noun or a substantive is not unknown, as sense A from the same entry attests:

> A statement which is true if any one of a number of component statements it includes is true. Cf. sense B. 8, exclusive n. 1. Obsolete.

So you could add this to your list of least-bad ideas:

> Winning this card game is *inclusive* of getting closest to 21 or the opponent going over 21?

> the *inclusive* of A or B happens iff [if and only if] at least one of A, B happens.

Comment: I upvoted because I was attracted to "inclusive" or "inclusion" myself for a while, although I still slightly prefer "alternative" because it's clearer that one could happen without the other than "inclusive"/"inclusion", and it's not a nonce word.

Answer (score -2):

I must say that while reading your explanation, at the point where you consider the first various possible terms, I said to myself "Why not use the term "alternative" (the alternative of A and B)?". It looks like the best option; however, it implies exclusion of one of the two and a verb "to alternate" does not mean "to occur as  one of two possibility or jointly". The noun "**concurrence**" is general enough in its meaning, though.

> (SOED) **2a** Joint action, cooperation

Moreover, the verb "**to concur**" means (SOED)

> "Act in concert, cooperate; Of causes, etc.: combine (to produce a result)".

Comment: Note this part of the description, which excludes *concurrence*: "**Concurrence** sounds like another description for intersection, as does conjunction, which is too jargony." How does your definition not mean *intersection*, if a concurrence suggests two causes "act[ing] in concert" or two causes as a "joint action"?

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin It does not infer intersection uniquely but it does include intersection and my understanding was that it should; so it shouldn't… I see; I'll read the question again.

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin It is **at least one of the two events**, which means that the two of them are allowed.

Comment: In my understanding, if event A happens and event B doesn't happen, that's not a *joint action*. For a joint action, it has to be A and B (both are joined; both cooperate); A happening alone is not included in that.

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin Strickly speaking I'd rather have it as you make it out, but in practice I suspect that the idea of joint action can be stretched to meaning action for which oen or more of the participants is responsible. Anyway, here that is out of the question: it's either one or both.

Comment: Like I said, I think "concurrence" sounds too much like "they both happen", while "alternative" (to me) doesn't necessarily imply exclusivity in typical probabilistic contexts: "To win this card game, you have the alternative of getting closest to 21, or your opponent going over 21." Clearly the possibilities don't exclude each other. "Winning this card game is represented by the concurrence of getting closest to 21 or the opponent going over 21" sounds awkward as a concurrence should typically be joined by an "and", not an "or", and "and" implies intersection.

Comment: @RiversMcForge Not really, here is the definition of "alternative" from the OALD: "a thing that you can choose to do or have to do out of two or more possibilities. In the SOED, sense 2 stating or offering either of two things; sense 3: Of two things: mutually exclusive; of one or more things: available in place of one another